# Could Not Load Type "xxxxxxx'

Tags: asp.net

I know this question was addressed already, but none of the solutions worked for me. I am getting the error "Could not load type 'Member_v2.rx_coupon'."

In my aspx file, I have

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="rx-coupon.aspx.cs" Inherits="Member_v2.rx_coupon" %>
```

and in my C# file, I have

```
namespace Member_v2
{
    public partial class rx_coupon:System.Web.UI.Page
    ....
```

Am I using Inherits="" incorrectly? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i would like to comment on your question but since my reputation is still low i can not at the moment.
So I will ask you this,
the name for the code behind is "rx-coupon",
while the name for the inheritance page is "rx_coupon" which differs so please check it again.

Comment: My files are named "rx-coupon", but my class that I'm using is "Member_v2.rx_coupon". I changed the name to match, but I still get the same error.

Comment: did you copy the code from a file to another? and when u changed it did you change the one in code behind?

Comment: I did not copy any code, and yes, I changed the names in both the aspx and cs files.

Comment: I ended up fixing it just by creating an entire new web form. I suppose build clean didn't clear the dll files.. thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome, good that it worked for you, well yea some sources online said maybe the dll files had a problem and some of them said delete all the inside of the bin file and rebuild the solution. Anw, Good Luck